# MPI_File_Iwrite, copying fprintf to buffer

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, printf

I'm doing some MPI programming and I've done lots of searching around and googling. I'm working to a tight deadline and it's 2AM here so thanks in advance for the responses.

Instead of writing to a file like this:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d %d %.12E %.12E %.12E %d\n", ii, jj, u_x, u_y, pressure, obstacles[ii * params.nx + jj]);
```

I want to use `MPI_file_Iwrite(....buf.....)`

This means I need the format exactly the same as above in fprintf but need it copied to a buffer (Char array).
Can anyone suggest a way to do this easily. I'm getting a bit stumped without some really laborious type conversions and `strcpy()`, `strcat()` in a big for loop etc..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need here is `sprintf` to print the above format to a buffer

given your example heres an example of the C code you will need

```
tmp = (char *) malloc(SIZE);
strcpy(tmp, filename);
sprintf(filename, "%d %d %.12E %.12E %.12E %d\n", ii, jj, u_x, u_y, pressure, obstacles[ii * params.nx + jj]);
```

Then the relevent `MPI` code

```
MPI_File fh;
MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_SELF, filename, MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_RDWR, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
MPI_File_set_view(fh, 0, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
MPI_File_iwrite(fh, buf, nints, MPI_INT, &request);
MPI_Wait( &request, &status );
MPI_File_close(&fh);
```

For a complete example see [here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_File_iwrite.html)

Comment: Use of `sprintf()` is strongly discouraged. One should use `snprintf()` instead. Also I don't think `sprintf`-ing into `filename` makes sense.